# Saving data from Table View

Tags: ios, swift3

I have entities setup in core data where I would like to save the days that the user has selected and the time from the date picker :

For e.g. [image]

I want to save Monday, Wednesday, Friday and 22:07. I can hook up the date picker to the viewcontroller to get the time. However how can I save the days that are selected ?

**Attempt 1 :**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell
        print(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
    }
```

return nil

**Attempt 2**

```
print("You selected \(indexPath.row.description)")
```

Successfully return the row number of the cell but not the UIlabel description.

**More info**

The days of the week are stored as UILabel as below : 
[image]

**Attempt 3 :**

```
  print(currentCell.contentView.description)
```

I also tried to add a navigation controller to add a save button to the top right and that doesn't seem to work either (the save button is going to the bottom left for some reason).

Would appreciate any help please! Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you haven't created IBOutlets for each UILabel that represents the day of the week and connected it to your ViewController.  Without that, you can't reference the UILabel.text value from code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MartinMuldoon. I've done that now. So when the user selects Monday and Thursday for e.g, how can I detect and save mondayLabel and ThursdayLabel to be read ?

Comment: You were certainly doing it right, using didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  I'll add a bit of code below.

Comment: Sure, thanks you. The aim is to be able to save all this and populate another TableView. The way the story board works is that the initial view controller is a tableViewController. You press the add button on it and the above tableViewController comes up. I tried to add a save button to the top right and that didn't work. Thanks once again.

Comment: I've updated the code.  Fully working in the simulator.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableView:didSelectRowAt` works in dynamic and static cells similarly.

Use the method `indexPathsForSelectedRows` (plural) to get **all** currently selected index paths, then use an array to get the weekdays rather than gathering the information from the cells.

The code maps the index paths of section 0 to their rows and maps the rows to the corresponding weekdays.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
     if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
         let rows = selectedRows.filter {$0.section == 0}.map{ $0.row}
         let filteredWeekdays = rows.map{ weekdays[$0] }
         print(filteredWeekdays)
     }
}
```

If you want to catch also deselecting a cell use the same code in `tableView:didDeselectRowAt` for example

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedWeekdays()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedWeekdays()
}

func selectedWeekdays()
{
    let weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        let rows = selectedRows.filter {$0.section == 0}.map{ $0.row}
        let filteredWeekdays = rows.map{ weekdays[$0] }
        print(filteredWeekdays)
    }
}
```

Consider to save the indices of the weekdays in Core Data rather than the string values. Then you can use the rows directly.

Comment: Thanks vadian! Sorry I was sick and couldn't reply earlier.  Could you kindly explain this please : https://pastebin.com/sRHnQTP1 
My understanding is that if selectedRows is true then selectedRows is filtered and mapped in a certain way.

Comment: Could you kindly explain what is being filtered and what is being mapped please ? For e.g. what does this mean and what does it do {$0.section == 0}.map{ $0.row} and same with this one  rows.map{ weekdays[$0] }. 


Thanks!

Comment: The `filter` function considers only index paths in section 0, the first `map` transforms the index paths to their row indexes (`[IndexPath]` -> `[Int]`) the second `map` transforms the row indexes to their corresponding weekday strings  (`[Int]` -> `[String]`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation vadian. If I want to read more about the above subject in swift, which topics/books/tutorials could I refer to? This is so I can practise more of above and deepen my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Reuse Identifiers.. Monday, Tuesday, etc. I've also created an array to hold the selected values.  Finally be sure to implement didDeselectRow, to remove values from the array.

```
import UIKit

class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var monday: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tuesday: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var wednesay: UILabel!

    var selectedDays: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let identifier = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.reuseIdentifier as! String
            print(identifier)
            switch identifier {
            case "Monday":
                selectedDays.append(identifier)
            case "Tuesday":
                 selectedDays.append(identifier)
            case "Wednesday":
                selectedDays.append(identifier)
            default:
                return
            }
        print(selectedDays.count)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let identifier = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.reuseIdentifier as! String
        print(identifier)
        switch identifier {
        case "Monday":
            selectedDays.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        case "Tuesday":
            selectedDays.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        case "Wednesday":
            selectedDays.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        default:
            return
        }
        print(selectedDays.count)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Martin. For e.g. one of my Outlets is called  @IBOutlet weak var tuesdayLabel: UILabel!

So when I write let selectedDayOfWeek = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!.tuesdayLabel.text   in didSelectRowAt,  I get an error saying that Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'tuesdayLabel'.